# jquery select all checkboxes inside a tab

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have several tabs.  Each tab has several nested elements that contain checkbox input elements.  I need to be able to select all / none of the the checkboxes within the selected tab.  I was hoping this would work:

```
$("#tabs").tabs().data("selected.tabs").('input[@type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

But it doesn't.  I was thinking that I could get the element of the selected tab and then iterate all the children of that element looking for checkboxes.  However, I am having trouble figuring out how to get the element (not index) of the selected element.  If someone knows how, please let me know.

EDIT:

I assumed everyone knew the structure of the jquery tabs.
The tabs are in a UL above and separate from the DIVs that actually contain the content and checkboxes for the tab.

```
<ul><li>tab0</li>... </ul><div id="tab0"> checkboxes here </div>
```

I need to find the selected tab and then find the div that corresponds to the tab.  I think the div is called the panel property but I can't figure out how to access that panel property once I find the tab.  Please see [jquery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: what happens when you do console.log($("#tabs").data("selected.tabs")); ?

Comment: The `@` is obsolete on attribute selectors. What version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: 1.3.2 core and 1.7.2 of ui.  I am new to jquery.  found that code on an old blog post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#tabs").tabs().data("selected.tabs").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: you got me down the right path.. thanks!  the full solution is :

$("#tabs div.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a "selected" tab  comes with a specific classname to identify it as the selected tab. You can easily identify this classname via firebug, or an equivalent. Assuming that classname is 'selected,' we could do the following:

```
$("#tabs .selected :checkbox:checked");
```